# snmptt MySQL error: Unable to connect to database

Tags: mysql, snmp, cacti

I have searched all google links without a result:
I'm using snmptt to store incoming traps in database.
I get this message in snmpttsystem.log file:

> Tue Jul  1 11:15:56 2014 MySQL error: Unable to connect to database:
>   Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (13)

I tryed connecting to localhost in snmptt.ini file and got this error in snmpttsystem.log file:

> Tue Jul  1 10:44:09 2014 MySQL error: Unable to connect to database:
>   Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (13)

I checked all the configurations in snmptt.ini many times, please any body have any idea.
any help will be apreciated.

Comment: What did you try? In other words, have you tried troubleshooting the SQL connection in any way at all? Can you connect from the command line using the same credentials as the application uses?

Comment: yes I have many services working on same sever and all working fine, also I can connect from command line .. it looks like the connection is not established and refused.